# Sharing my visual studio 2017 pro key

Tags: visual-studio, license-key

I just activate my visual studio 2017 license today (I've got one license from MSDN) 
And I wanna know if I can share the license key with friends like a VL (volume license) or no ?

Thank in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Your MSDN subscription licenses you (and only you) to use Visual Studio (emphasis mine)

> Visual Studio subscriptions (formerly called MSDN subscriptions) are licensed on a **per-user** basis. **One person** can use the software to design, develop, test, or demonstrate his or her programs on any number of devices.
>   [Source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/subscriptions/cc150618.aspx)

However, there is [Visual Studio Community Edition](https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/community/) that lone developers are entitled to use. Companies that have 5 or less developers can also make use of this edition without breaching the EULA.

> **For Individuals**
>   Any individual developer can use Visual Studio Community to create their own free or paid apps.
>
> **For organizations**
>   An unlimited number of users within an organization can use Visual Studio Community for the following scenarios: in a classroom learning environment, for academic research, or for contributing to open source projects.
>
> **For all other usage scenarios:**
>   In non-enterprise organizations, up to five users can use Visual Studio Community. In enterprise organizations (meaning those with >250 PCs or >$1 Million US Dollars in annual revenue), no use is permitted beyond the open source, academic research, and classroom learning environment scenarios described above.